# Webbrowser control onclick event

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I have a code that clicks an html element but it doesn't fire its java script code, in VBA I used to call "initEvent" in order to invoke a java script event.
I have searched the web and haven't found a suitable solution.

There's a working solution, but it's not quite useful in most cases, placing a java script code in the url and navigating to it, however there's a need for the location of the html element which is a problem sometimes.

The code I use in order to do a click in the html element :

```
el.InvokeMember("onclick");
```

Also tried :

```
el.InvokeMember("click");
```

The code that I place in the url and find not too much useful :

```
wb.Navigate("javascript: document.getElementsByClassName('something')[0].click();void(0);");
```

I hope to receive a working solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, do you want to fire a click event in a web page i.e JavaScript or on web browser control i.e VB?

Comment: WebBrowser is a c# type, when I fire a click event it's not invoking its javascript.
In simple words, it clicks but not firing its java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, a very original solve I'd say.
So basically, I've thought about it this way.
Finding an element that I already have is not comfortable at all, so the java script navigate didn't seem useful, however, I thought of changing it to fit any element, the question was how.

The answer I came up with, what if I'd focus the specific element and then use a javascript to click on the focused element, and it worked.

So the fixed code :

```
el.Focus();
wb.Navigate("javascript: document.activeElement.click();void(0);");
```

I hope it'll be useful to some of you.