# how to handle the onclick attribute c# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elementyButton in elementButton)
{
 if (elementyButton.GetAttribute("onclick") == "ExecuteBid('46097');")
 {
  elementyButton.InvokeMember("click");
 }
}
```

I intend to program an automatic click, but the click can only happen in a specific location, the only attribute different from the others is onclick. I can use the class, for example, but the site has several buttons with the same class, if I click through the class the click will be on all elements that use the class, and there are many, so the click will occur on all these elements, but I just want to click on a specific element and the only attribute that differentiates one element from the other is onclick, but giving getattribute on onclik does not return anything, I would like to know how to access this onclick attribute.

Comment: Where/when is this code executed? -- Note that you can get `onclick` as an attribute, but `GetAttribute()` only return a string. You use that method to determine whether the attribute is present (the string is not empty), but the real attribute's value is contained in the underlying COM object, which can be cast to the `IHtmlElement` interface (e.g., `dynamic onclick = ([HtmlElement].DomElement as IHTMLElement).onclick`), from which you can then access the `JavaScriptType` COM object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550636/webbrowser-control-onclick-event