# how to click a button using the onclick attribute c# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to click on button that has the following html:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="ExecuteBid('46160');" title="ExecuteBid" class="btn btn-custom3">Bid</a>
```

The problem is that the only attribute I can use is onclick, because there are more buttons on the site that use the same name as href, title and class, if I use any of these the click will be on more than one button, and I just want to click on this specific button.

if this button had an id, the code would be:

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsById("Id");
elementButton.InvokeMember("click");
```

However, this button has no id. How to click on this button using the onclick parameter?

Comment: Try finding the next parent control that has an id, or is otherwise identifiable. Then navigate through the child positions to the object you are trying to fire the click event for.

Comment: Do you have other Anchors with Attribute `title` that equals `ExecuteBid` there? As menrioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65866424/7444103) about the same matter, you can filter out a  collection of elements based on the `onclick` attribute content. If you don't find it (the filtered collection is empty), you're probably searching for it in the *wrong place* (`IFrame`?). That's why it's important that you -  as already asked - show when, where and how you're executing your code.